# Greeter doesn't update user background

Tags: greeter

I'm having a little issue with the greeter. It's supposed that the greeter shows user name and user background (wallpaper) but in my case the wallpaper is not being updated, never mind how many times I change it, greeter always show Hera defaults background.
Any idea?
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Your background should be coming from /usr/share/backgrounds or the Greeter won't pick it up.

Comment: It doesn't work :(